# Cassandra Write Timeout - Tried whatever I think I can debug/analyse still no luck. Help me with your inputs/direction

Tags: java, cassandra

We are running Cassandra 3.9 cluster on AWS in 9 nodes. And I see we are getting once a week Write Timeouts and I was preparing my checklist to identify and resolve the problem. The checklist and finding are as follows

1. Any spike on Cassandra nodes
   **Findings**: All nodes CPU running on 20-50%
2. Any wide partitions issue
   **Finding**: Yes we have few wide partitions but in the process of addressing them. But don't see any writings on that particular day/moment
3. GC Load
   **Finding**: From the gc.log I see not much GC blocking application threads @ the same time when write timeout occurred. I see application threads are blocked in few nodes for less than 200ms. And we set write timeouts to 60sec for counters 15sec
4. Any finding in system.log
   **Finding**: I see only one error in few of the nodes as stated below. **Will this cause any problem**

```
WARN  [CounterMutationStage-76] 2021-01-21 07:11:29,101 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:169 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[CounterMutationStage-76,5,main]: {}
java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue.<init>(Recycler.java:225) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.Recycler$DefaultHandle.recycle(Recycler.java:180) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at io.netty.util.Recycler.recycle(Recycler.java:141) ~[netty-all-4.0.39.Final.jar:4.0.39.Final]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$Builder.recycle(BTree.java:836) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.btree.BTree$Builder.build(BTree.java:1089) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.build(PartitionUpdate.java:587) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.maybeBuild(PartitionUpdate.java:577) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.partitions.PartitionUpdate.iterator(PartitionUpdate.java:437) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$8.iterator(Iterables.java:713) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.iterators(Iterables.java:508) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.access$100(Iterables.java:60) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$2.iterator(Iterables.java:498) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$3.transform(Iterables.java:512) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables$3.transform(Iterables.java:509) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:548) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:361) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:160) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toCollection(Iterables.java:337) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toArray(Iterables.java:315) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Striped.bulkGet(Striped.java:146) ~[guava-18.0.jar:na]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.grabCounterLocks(CounterMutation.java:144) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CounterMutation.applyCounterMutation(CounterMutation.java:122) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$9.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1473) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:2486) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$FutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:164) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService$LocalSessionFutureTask.run(AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:136) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.SEPWorker.run(SEPWorker.java:109) [apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
```

5. I don't see any other ERROR/WARNING logs in system.log

Please guide me on what other things I should be looking at to pinpoint the issue... Any more details like configuration required please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted looks like it's happening as part of a mutation, so it could be the root of a request timeout. It looks like this error is known and fixed in 3.11. Are you able to upgrade?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12928
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13114

Comment: Thank You Adam. This timeout is happening like once in a week or so but not frequently in a week. Then I thought this is no issue with version 3.9. If there is a load then this could occur or what could be the case?

Comment: May be caused by high load, or a long GC pause (due to load or compaction, repair, etc).